# Mapping timeseries sequence input shape to desired output shape using EinsumDense

Tags: tensorflow, numpy-einsum

Can anyone help me understand how to handle compressing/expanding the dimension of a tensor using EinsumDense?

I have a timeseries (not NLP) input tensor of the shape `(batch, horizon, features)` wherein the intended output is `(1, H, F)`; `H` is an arbitrary horizon and `F` is an arbitrary feature size. I'm actually using `EinsumDense` as my Feed Forward Network in a transformer encoder module and as a final dense layer in the transformer's output. The FFN should map `(1, horizon, features)` to `(1, H, features)` and the final dense layer should map `(1, H, features)` to `(1, H, F)`.

My current equation is `shf,h->shf` for the FFN, and `shf,hfyz->syz` for the dense layer, however I'm getting a less than optimal result as compared to my original setup where there was no change in the horizon length and my equations were `shf,h->shf` and `shf,hz->shz` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents,

First, an *intuitive understanding* of the transformer encoder: Given `(batch, horizon, features)`, the attention mechanism tries to find a weighted linear combination of the projected `features`. The resulting weights are learned via attention scores obtained by operating *between* `features`, *over* each `horizon`. The FFN layer that comes next should be a linear combination of values *within* `features`.

Coming to `EinsumDense` by way of example we have two tensors:

**a**: Data (your input tensor to `EinsumDense`)
**b**: Weights (`EinsumDense`'s internal weights tensor)

```
# create random data in a 3D tensor
a = tf.random.uniform(minval=1, maxval=3, shape=(1,2,3), dtype=tf.int32)
# [[[1, 2, 2],
#   [2, 2, 1]]]
```

**shf,h->shf**:
This just scales the individual features.

```
b = tf.random.uniform(minval=2, maxval=4, shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int32) 
# [3, 2]
tf.einsum('shf,h->shf', a, b)
# [[[3, 6, 6],   #1st feature is scaled with 3
#   [4, 4, 2]]]] #2nd feature is scaled with 2
```

**shf,hz->shz**: This does a linear combination `within` features

```
b = tf.random.uniform(minval=2, maxval=4, shape=(2,6), dtype=tf.int32)
# [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#  [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3]]
tf.einsum('shf,hz->shz', a, b)
# [[[15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
#   [10, 10, 10, 15, 10, 15]]]
# every value is a linear combination of the first feature [1, 2, 2] with b. The first value is sum([1,2,2]*3)
```

**The above two resembles the `transformer encoder` architecture, with a feature scaling layer. And the output structure is preserved `(batch, H, F)`**

**shf,hfyz->syz**: This does both `between` features and `within` features combination.

```
b = tf.random.uniform(minval=2, maxval=4, shape=(2,3,4,5), dtype=tf.int32)
tf.einsum('shf,hfyz->syz', a,b)
# each element output `(i,j)` is a dot product of a and b[:,:,i,j] 
# first element is tf.reduce_sum(a*b[:,:,0,0])
```

**Here the output (s,y,z), y doesnt correspond to `horizon` and z doesn't correspond to `features`, but a combination of values *between* them.**